# Что нужно добавить в мой класс,чтобы вектор мог принимать rvalue ссылку на объект этого класса

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Есть мной реализованный класс UniquePtr. Мне надо чтобы корректно работал метод push_back для вектора, состоящего из элементов этого класса:

```
  std::vector<UniquePtr<Person>> v;
            UniquePtr<Alice> alice(new Alice);
            v.push_back(std::move(alice));
```

конструктор перемещения

```
  UniquePtr(UniquePtr&& other) noexcept : ptr_(std::move(other.ptr_)) {
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
    }
```

Что нужно добавить в исходный класс?

Comment: Если вы реализовали конструктор перемещения для UniquePtr - push_back сработает корректно.

Comment: @Ariox,добавил свой конструктор

Comment: *в исходный класс* - ¿это в какой?

Comment: Пригодился бы [mcve].

Comment: И еще текст ошибки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор перемещения для поддержки наследников реализуется примерно так:

```
template<class T>
class UniquePtr{
template<class U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, bool> = true>
UniquePtr(UniquePtr<U>&& other) noexcept : ptr_(std::move(other.ptr_)) {
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу в вопросе наследования, но вроде обычный конструктор перемещения и так прекрасно работает с наследованием?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, исходный вопрос плохо сформулирован, пришлось включить навыки телепатии. В вопросе есть `UniquePtr<Person>` и `UniquePtr<Alice>`, второй нужно приводить к первому, а `Alice`, вероятно, унаследован от `Person`.